# PKCS11Exception: CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED

Tags: java, pkcs#11, hsm, softhsm

I installed Softhsm v 2.2 and Started working with PkCS#11 Java API that on

Operations:

1. 1.Slot Creation

   2. Token Creation
   3. Key Generation
   4. Encryption
   5. Signing
   6. Key Retrieving

I am getting below exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
        at SoftHSM.main(SoftHSM.java:47)
    Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_OpenSession(Native Method)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:215)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionManager.getOpSession(SessionManager.java:150)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.Token.<init>(Token.java:151)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.initToken(SunPKCS11.java:858)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:367)
        ... 2 more
```

My softhsm.cfg

```
    name = SoftHSM
    library = Z:\SOFTHSM_INSTALL\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll

    slot= 0

    attributes(generate, *, *) = {
       CKA_TOKEN = true
    }
    attributes(generate, CKO_CERTIFICATE, *) = {
       CKA_PRIVATE = false
    }
    attributes(generate, CKO_PUBLIC_KEY, *) = {
       CKA_PRIVATE = false
    }
```

After I tried another after restart of PC:

```
    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
    Available slots:
    Slot 0
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x0
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:
            Initialized:      no
            User PIN init.:   no
            Label:

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin> softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 1 --label "A token"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ******
    Please reenter SO PIN: ******
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID: Slot 1 does not exist.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin> softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 0 --label "0 token"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ******
    Please reenter SO PIN: ******
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    The token has been initialized.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
    Available slots:
    Slot 1526831955
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x5b019b53
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:    cafa9efc5b019b53
            Initialized:      yes
            User PIN init.:   yes
            Label:            0 token
    Slot 1
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x1
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:
            Initialized:      no
            User PIN init.:   no
            Label:

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin> softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 0 --label "B token"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ******
    Please reenter SO PIN: ******
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID: Slot 0 does not exist.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin> softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 5 --label "s5 token"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ******
    Please reenter SO PIN: ******
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID: Slot 5 does not exist.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin> softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 0 --label "1 token"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ******
    Please reenter SO PIN: ******
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID: Slot 0 does not exist.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>
```

But Now it says its initialized, but still I dont know what slot id i have to provide . I tried with slot=1, slot=1526831955 but I am getting

```
  sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID
```

Comment: I have not use this Java API but it seems that token erros(CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED) generally occur when tokens does not exist or corrupted. Could you check "slot= 0" is exist ? Could you check with other token IDs.

Comment: how to create a  new token , I am not able to create. Anybody uses Java API for Softhsm ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SoftHSM2 java not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673782/softhsm2-java-not-working)