# SoftHSM2 java not working

Tags: java, pkcs#11, hsm, softhsm

I am trying to do POC on SoftHSM 2 , but some how I am getting below issue .

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
            at SoftHSM.main(SoftHSM.java:50)
        Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID
            at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetSlotInfo(Native Method)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:365)
            ... 2 more
```

HSM Config File :

```
    # SoftHSM v2 configuration file
    name= SoftHSM2
    library = C:\SoftHSM2\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll
    slot=1
```

If I comment slot=1 , then I am getting

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
            at SoftHSM.main(SoftHSM.java:50)
        Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED
            at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_OpenSession(Native Method)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:215)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionManager.getOpSession(SessionManager.java:150)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.Token.<init>(Token.java:151)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.initToken(SunPKCS11.java:858)
            at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:367)
            ... 2 more
```

due to some reason it is not getting intizlized. Does anybody can help me on get it running with Java .

My PC Details :
Winn 10: 64 bit
I have added VC++ distributaable as per requirement from softHSM.

I am attaching my java Source file

```
    import java.security.Key;
    import java.security.KeyStore;
    import java.security.Provider;
    import java.security.Security;

    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11;

    public class TestClass {


         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                // Set up the Sun PKCS 11 provider
               // String configName = "Z:\\SOFTHSM_INSTALL\\etc\\softhsm2.conf";

             String configName = "softhsm2.cfg";

                Provider p = new SunPKCS11(configName);

                if (-1 == Security.addProvider(p)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("could not add security provider");
                }

                // Load the key store
                char[] pin = "mypin".toCharArray();
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
                keyStore.load(null, pin);

                // AES key
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(), "AES");
                Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeySpec.getEncoded(), "AES");

                keyStore.setKeyEntry("AA", key, "1234".toCharArray(), null);
                keyStore.store(null); //this gives me the exception.

         }

    }
```

Please help me guys.

Seems to be I dont have any slots with token initialized. So trying to initialize the token. but getting below error. Can someone help me to identify mistake I did.

```
    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
    Available slots:
    Slot 0
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x0
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:
            Initialized:      no
            User PIN init.:   no
            Label:

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 0 --label Kumar
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ****
    Please reenter SO PIN: ****
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    ERROR 30: Could not initialize the token.
```

Solution:

I verified Windows Event Log as per Jariq, it says application corrupted.
I did re-install the app for windows  "softhsm2.msi".

and executed script is below here for Reference to people like me .

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
    (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd\

    C:\>cd SoftHSM2

    C:\SoftHSM2>cd bin

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 0 --label "My token 1"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN:
    ERROR: The length of the PIN is out of range.
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    ^C
    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 0 --label "My token 1"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ****
    Please reenter SO PIN: ****
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID: Slot 0 does not exist.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
    Available slots:
    Slot 1526831955
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x5b019b53
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:    cafa9efc5b019b53
            Initialized:      yes
            User PIN init.:   yes
            Label:            0 token
    Slot 1
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x1
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:
            Initialized:      no
            User PIN init.:   no
            Label:

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 1 --label "My token 1"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ****
    Please reenter SO PIN: ****
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    The token has been initialized.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
    Available slots:
    Slot 1242738572
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x4a12af8c
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:    00fbfb20ca12af8c
            Initialized:      yes
            User PIN init.:   yes
            Label:            My token 1
    Slot 1526831955
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x5b019b53
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:    cafa9efc5b019b53
            Initialized:      yes
            User PIN init.:   yes
            Label:            0 token
    Slot 2
        Slot info:
            Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x2
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Token present:    yes
        Token info:
            Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
            Model:            SoftHSM v2
            Hardware version: 2.2
            Firmware version: 2.2
            Serial number:
            Initialized:      no
            User PIN init.:   no
            Label:

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --init-token --slot 2 --label "My token 2"
    === SO PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter SO PIN: ****
    Please reenter SO PIN: ****
    === User PIN (4-255 characters) ===
    Please enter user PIN: ****
    Please reenter user PIN: ****
    The token has been initialized.

    C:\SoftHSM2\bin>
```

After this I have more than one token initialized . Thanks you verymuch **Jariq**.

Comment: You did include the exception but you forgot to include the code which can be used to reproduce it.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry i will add right now .

Comment: Check if your user account has permission to write into `C:\SoftHSM2\var\softhsm2\tokens` directory and check windows event log for more detailed error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented in [JDK 8 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) you need to use `slotListIndex` attribute instead of `slot` attribute in the Sun PKCS#11 Provider configuration file.

Following configuration file is working fine for me with the test application you have provided:

```
# Sun PKCS#11 provider configuration file for SoftHSMv2
name = SoftHSM2
library = d:\SoftHSM2\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll 
slotListIndex = 0
```

SoftHSMv2 always returns all initialized slots/tokens...

[image: First token in Pkcs11Admin application]

...plus one additional which is not initialized and which returns `CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED` error for almost every PKCS#11 call...

[image: Second token in Pkcs11Admin application]

...and by using `slotListIndex = 0` you are instructing Sun PKCS#11 Provider to use only the first returned slot/token.

Comment: I am downloading https://sourceforge.net/projects/pkcs11admin/files/latest/download?source=directory for to see slots info as you mention jariq. I will try out and upadte same here .

Comment: I have updated main post , but having issue with intialize token

Answer (score 0):

Default Softhsm2 configuration file should be like this

```
# SoftHSM v2 configuration file
directories.tokendir = C:\SoftHSM2\var\softhsm2\tokens\
objectstore.backend = file
log.level = INFO
slots.removable = false
```