# How can I mock a hardware secure module (HSM) in Java for a security provide?

Tags: java, hsm

In our project we are using an openID connect implementation. The implementation takes care of creating and signing JWTs. They use the nimbus-jose-jwt library for this.

I want to test if we add a HSM as a security provider if it will get used by the openId connect implementation. I don't have a machine with a HSM for testing purposes so I need to mock this behaviour.

Would I have to implement a Provider like in [HowToImplAProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) (or use a library that did this) or is there a shortcut to have something that behaves like a Provider just for testing purposes?

Comment: Maybe an humble-test would by enough for your situation? See http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html

Comment: I need to add the provider and I want to see that the supplied provider is used by the openID connect implementation. A Provider class that I want to use has to come from a signed jar according to the link I posted. The pattern you linked will probably not work here.

My current approach would be to insert my Provider class in the configuration, run my application, and then set a breakpoint at the place where the signing happens and see if the Provider that I setup is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Windows build of SoftHSM2 (can be found [here](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows)) and then used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673782/softhsm2-java-not-working) to add it to my project.